# Fragments view reference gets destroyed - viewpager, trying to change content dynamically

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager attached to a tabbed layout and its on page changed listener looks like this

```
 private void setPageChangeListener(FragmentStatePagerAdapter pagerAdapter) {
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener () {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            FragmentLifecycleHelper fragment = (FragmentLifecycleHelper) pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.onResumeFragment();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now in my child fragments i create the views like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_account, container, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "OnCreateView()");
    printLog();
    return mFragmentView;
}
```

which saves a reference to the view (i assume getView() does the same).

Whatsoever, now the called interface method is supposed to change the icon and the fab onClick listener of the hosting activity, the problem is whenever onResume is called the view reference is null.

This is my onResumeFragment()

```
  /********************* INTERFACE METHODS ******************************/
@Override
public void onResumeFragment() {
    Log.d(TAG,"onResumeFragment()");
    printLog();
    if(mFragmentView != null){
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFabIcon(MainActivity.FAB_ICON.PLUS);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFabClickListener(v -> {
            // TODO
        });
    }

}
```

printLog() just prints the current status of the view reference.

Whenever i log this onCreateView of Fragment 1 gets called when i am in fragment 0 or 3 (so neighbour fragments) onResume then gets called when i actually switch to the correct view. But then getView() and my own reference both return null and i get a NPE if i try to access the hosting activity

Comment: Did you tried to set off screen page limit value to view pager. Try setting its value to no. of fragments/tabs present.  mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(No.of_Frag);

Comment: This would cache all available fragments which is what i wanted to prevent. Nevertheless if found a workaround overwriting `setUserVisibility()` instead of the listener approach.